# 3D parametric equations for an elliptical orbit, using inclination angle

Tags: conic-sections, polar-coordinates, parametric, spherical-coordinates

I am modelling planetary orbits using parametric equations, with the Sun at (0,0).

In 2D, it's quite straightforward ($a$ is the semi-major axis length and $e$ is eccentricity)

$$ x\left(t\right)=a\ cos\left(t\right)+ae,\\
y\left(t\right)=a\sqrt{1-e^2}\ sin\left(t\right)\\$$

However, I'm struggling to extend the model to 3D. If I use spherical polar coordinates, $\phi$ is the angle between the Z-axis and the vector $\vec{OP}$, where P is the position of the planet.

As orbital inclination is measured from the positive x-axis to $\vec{OP}$, then $i=\frac{\pi}{2}-\phi$. [From this diagram,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/de28x.png) $z=\frac{r}{tan(\phi)}$.

If I use the polar equation $r=\frac{a\left(1-e^2\right)}{1+ecos\ \theta}$, then $$z\left(t\right)=\frac{a\left(1-e^2\right)}{\left(1+ecost\right)tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-i\right)}=\frac{a\left(1-e^2\right)tan\left(i\right)}{\left(1+ecost\right)}$$

However, when I graph Venus and Earth's orbit on the same axis, I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2MzX.png) result in MATLAB. I don't believe there are any errors in my code, so it must be an error in my mathematics.

**tl;dr** Is there a better way to model ellipses that have a specific angle of inclination?

```
function [] = orbitEquations_3d(planetName, eccentricity, a, inclination)
% initialise (1-e^2) and sqrt(1-e^2)

    oneMinusE_sq = (1-eccentricity^2);
    sqrtOneMinusE_sq = sqrt(oneMinusE_sq);

    % convert angle of inclination from deg to radians
    inclination = inclination/180 * pi; 

% planet name
    disp(planetName);
    
% display equations
    disp("parametric");
    fprintf("x(t) = %.6f*cos(t) + %.6f\n", a, eccentricity*a);
    fprintf("y(t) = %.6f*sin(t)\n", a * sqrtOneMinusE_sq);
    fprintf("z(t) = %.6f*tan(%.6f)/(1+%.6fcos(t)) \n", a * oneMinusE_sq, inclination, eccentricity);
    fprintf("\n\n");
end
```

Comment: I'd suggest to compute the coordinates of vectors $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ corresponding to major and minor semi-axis, then to write the parametric equation of the ellipse as $C+\vec a\cos t+\vec b\sin t$, where $C$ is the center of the ellipse.

Answer (score 1):

This question was asked quite a while ago, but perhaps an answer is still of use.  I believe this answer is correct, though it's possible I have not adapted the approach which I suggest thoroughly enough to your statement of the problem to ensure that it helps.

Assuming:  (at zero inclination) orbital ellipse is in X-Y plane, left-most focus is at origin, semi-major axis is along the $x$ axis, semi-minor axis is parallel to the $y$ axis:

[Orbital ellipse at zero inclination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaqyB.png)

One way to see a solution to this problem is to view the orbital ellipse edge-on, which shows that the $x$ and $z$ coordinates of all points on the ellipse are readily expressed in terms of the angle of inclination (from the positive x axis).  This looks like the following for an inclination of Pi/4:

[Edge-on view of orbital ellipse at Pi/4 inclination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CLHw.png)

This edge-on image of the ellipse would be equivalent to the hypotenuse $\rho$ in your diagram: https://i.stack.imgur.com/de28x.png

As you can see from your diagram (in which $r$ would be $x\left(t\right)$), and using your above definitions for $x\left(t\right)$ and $y\left(t\right)$, we would have, for an inclination angle $i$ (which would be the angle $\frac{\pi}{2}-\phi$ in your diagram), the $x$ coordinate varying as $x\left(t\right)\cdot\cos\left(i\right)$, and the $z$ coordinate varying as $x\left(t\right)\cdot\sin\left(i\right)$

So, the coordinates of any point on the ellipse inclined at angle $i$ to the positive $x$ axis, would be:
$$X\left(t,i\right)=x\left(t\right)\cdot\cos\left(i\right)$$
$$Y\left(t,i\right)=y\left(t\right)$$
$$Z\left(t,i\right)=x\left(t\right)\cdot\sin\left(i\right)$$